# External async funtion in Cypress

Tags: node.js, async-await, es6-promise, cypress

I need to call the external function inside the Cypress process. 
I need to do this because the element id is dynamic, so I get it in my external API.

Follow the exeple.
The async function is "helper.ElementToClick".

```
const helper = require("../../../helper")

describe('Test', function() {
    it('First', async function() {
        cy.visit('https://www.*****.com/');

        const idElement = await helper.ElementToClick();

        cy.get('#' + idElement).click();
    })
})
```

But this code do not work.

Answer (score 0):

Does it help if you get the element to click in `before()`?

```js
const helper = require("../../../helper")

describe('Test', function() {
    let idElement;
    before(async () => {
        idElement = await helper.ElementToClick();
    });

    it('First', function() {
        cy.visit('https://www.*****.com/');
        cy.get('#' + idElement).click();
    });
});
```

Comment: No, beacuse I need to call async function more times durynd de porocess.

Comment: `before` should be in `describe` not `it`

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap it in a custom command.  We are using async commands inside of custom commands similar to this:

```
const helper = require("../../../helper");

describe('Test', function() {
    it('First', async function() {
        cy.visit('https://www.*****.com/');

        cy.getElementId().then(idElement => {
            cy.get('#' + idElement).click();
        });
    });
});

Cypress.Commands.add("getElementId", async () => {
  return await helper.ElementToClick();
});
```